# Rails: Appending methods to activerecord (the right way?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm messing around with creating a rails gem and I'm having trouble adding methods to ActiveRecord. Let's say I want to do the following:

```
class DemoModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  custom_method :first_argument, :second_argument
end
```

In order to make this work, I throw in the following:

```
module DemoMethod

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods       
    def custom_method(*fields)
      @my_fields = fields
    end
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, DemoMethod)
```

So far, so good.

The problem is, I then want to access that my_fields variable from the instance of the model. For example, I might open up form_for with something like:

```
module ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper
  def fields_for(record_name, record_object, options = {}, &block)
    the_fields = record_object.<I WANNA ACCESS @my_fields HERE!!!>.html_safe
    # ...
  end
end
```

The difficulty is, 'custom_method' only seems to work if I set the helper as a class method, but that means .self is now the Model (DemoModel) instead of the DemoModel object on which I want to work. I could pass in the object manually with "custom_method self, :first_argument, :second_argument", but it seems a little clumsy to ask the users of my wonderful "custom_method" gem to have to prepend 'self' to their list of arguments.

So, the question is, how would a wiser Rails person set values for a specific object through custom_method, and then retrieve them somewhere else, such as fields_for?

As always, any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `self.included` and `ClassMethods` adds the methods as class methods.

Defining methods normally within the module, and then including them, is the way to create ordinary instance methods. Like so:

```
module DemoMethod

   def custom_method(*fields)
    @my_fields = fields
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, DemoMethod)
```